# How to get word in php which contains colon(:)?

Tags: php, regex, search, preg-match

I have a word `Hello How are you :chinu i am :good` i want to get the word which contains `:` like `:chinu` and `:good`

My code:

```
<?php
  //$string='Hello How are you :chinu i am :good';
  //echo strtok($string, ':');  

  $string='Hello How are you :chinu i am :good';
  preg_match('/:([:^]*)/', $string, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
?>
```

Above code i am getting `Array ( [0] => : [1] => )` But not getting the exact text. Please help me.

Thanks
Chinu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get all matches you need to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). As far as your regular expression goes your negated class is backwards; matching any character of: `:`, `^` "zero or more" times and will not match what you expect.

You stated in the comments about the "records" being printed twice, this is because you print the `$matches` array itself instead of printing the group **index** which only displays the match results.

```
preg_match_all('/:\S+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: HI you have written `a-z` but it may be comes Number and Special Charactes. Can you please update your answer

Comment: Yes @vks I want to get single array. All are posted answer is coming twice record. If i have 500 colon(:) in the array but your code i am getting 1000. So its bad.

Comment: You have print the zero indexing array please print `$matches` i am getting the twice record.

Answer (score 6):

```
:\S+
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/43

```
$re = "/:\\S+/im";
$str = "Hello How are you :chinu i am :good";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: The extra `\` and the pattern flags `i` and `m` are unnecessary in your php code.  There are no `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]` expressions to make case-insensitive, nor are there any `.` (dots / any characters) to force to match line return characters.  (as shown by hwnd's answer)

Answer (score 4):

So you would need to do something like the following to match the characters up to the space:

```
preg_match_all('/:[^ ]+/', $string, $matches);
```

or if you're looking for alpha-only characters you might use the following:

```
preg_match_all('/:[A-Za-z]+/', $string, $matches);
```

The array you would look for would be `$matches[0]` at this point.

```
print_r($matches)

print_r($matches[0])
```

You can always reassign the matches sub array with something like this:

```
$matchesArray = $matches[0]
```

Comment: NOt working its coming `Array ( [0] => :chinu i am [1] => chinu i am ) `

Comment: Your edited answer also getting wrong output `Array ( [0] => :chinu [1] => chinu )` I need `Array ( [0] => :chinu [1] => :good)`

Comment: Move the colon inside the group. Updated again.

Comment: Ah, the grouping was the issue.